# Users can't see custom actions on record pages

Tags: permission-sets

I have some actions (Buttons, Links, and Actions on the object) on record pages that invoke flows. The user accounts have the "Run Flows" permission, and they have the record type available to them that the page layout containing the "Mobile & Lightning Actions" happens to use.

Anything else that could be preventing these buttons from appearing?

For what it's worth, the flows contain nodes to invoke approval processes as well as send emails.

Even when I set the flow to run in system context, the buttons don't appear.

Thanks

Comment: do the actions have conditional visibility that affects their presence? do the flows have enumerated profiles that restrict access (see flow _F_ access levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out -- I was using lightning record pages, and the page layout assignments didn't accommodate for the profiles that were being tested against. So when they weren't in the page layout, the fields weren't available in the lightning record pages.